# How do i run adobe air application without Adobe air player?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, animation, air

i dowload some animation from http://www.3dfreeair.com . so how can i run without Adobe AIR ?. How can i install in linux os ?.

I am beginner so don't mistake me . i dont know anything about air  . plz guys tech me about this .

Answer (score 8):

You can't run them without Adobe AIR...

You need to install it from here: http://get.adobe.com/air/

Comment: is it possiable to install linux system

Comment: yes, After that instllation .  Animations are working now . it is interesting and superb